# Memory performance difference between Activity Monitor and Instruments

Tags: xcode, memory, instruments, video-card

My xcode project uses OpenGL 3.2 to draw. When running the profiler the allocation instruments shows a healthy behaviour (allocating and deallocating) but when observing the Activity Monitor the memory usage rises rapidly to ~ 2GB in 3 mins. I run the same program on other macs and the Activity Monitor shows only a 40MB memory usage. I run the same project on the same OS version 10.8 and same Xcode version 4.4.